# certificate signed pdf

Tags: pdf, adobe, ssl, adobe-reader, certificates

Our Company uses pdf's secured by an .pfx. You must import the .pfx - certificate to read this document. I've tested evince but it can't handle that. It works fine with the latest Adobe Reader for unix - but i've read that there are much of security gaps.

Is there any other solution?

Comment: https://mail.gnome.org/archives/evince-list/2012-August/msg00008.html points to https://github.com/diaz/evince-signatures  (not tested it but that might be what you need)